# Formatting a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, formatting, rubocop

I need to **programmatically** format a Ruby hash like this one:

```rb
{
  type: "Processors::GroupRows",
  position: 1,
  config:
   {columns:
     [{strategy: "concat_uniq",
       local_column: "all_emails",
       source_column: "email"},
      {strategy: "concat_uniq",
       local_column: "all_phones",
       source_column: "phone"},
      {strategy: "count", local_column: "total_ads", source_column: "_id"},
      {strategy: "sum_int",
       local_column: "total_vacancies",
       source_column: "vacancies"}],
    group_by_column: "employer",
    select_row_columns:
     [{strategy: "maximum",
       column_type: "date",
       filter_column: "modified_at",
       insert_columns: [{source_column: "*"}]}]}
}
```

Into something like this:

```rb
{
  type: "Processors::GroupRows",
  position: 1,
  config: {
    columns: [ # this could also be '[{' and to save the extra indent
      {
        strategy: "concat_uniq",
        local_column: "all_emails",
        source_column: "email"
      }, {
        strategy: "concat_uniq",
        local_column: "all_phones",
        source_column: "phone"
      }, {
        strategy: "count",
        local_column: "total_ads",
        source_column: "_id"
      }, {
        strategy: "sum_int",
        local_column: "total_vacancies",
        source_column: "vacancies"
      }
    ],
    group_by_column: "employer",
    select_row_columns: [
      {
        strategy: "maximum",
        column_type: "date",
        filter_column: "modified_at",
        insert_columns: [{source_column: "*"}]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried Rubocop, different formatters but I always put a ton of time into it with no results.

Highly appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

So far I found this to work, using `pretty_print` as formatter and fixing the output.

It's not using Rubocop, so not highly customizable and might break.

```rb
  puts attrs
    .ai(indent: -2, plain: true)
    .gsub(/:([A-Za-z_]+)\s+=>\s+/, "\\1: ")
    .gsub(/},\s+{/, '}, {')
```

Comment: Not sure why you would need this output but [`JSON#pretty_generate`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-pretty_generate) will get you fairly close although the "keys" will be wrapped in quotes as Strings per JSON spec.